# HBASE_HOME directory in Cloudera 5.3.0

Tags: hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

In CDH 5.3.0 after adding HBase as a service, I need to copy few jars into HBASE_HOME/lib directory. I am not able to find it in the cluster deployed.

Answer (score 5):

For Cloudera CDH5 `$HBASE_HOME/lib` is in `/usr/lib/hbase/lib/` directory.
I've successfully used this location to put Phoenix library 3rd party jars.

Comment: Thanks SashaEgorov, will try it.